# Can JAXB handle java.time objects?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-8, java-time

I know [JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding) can marshal/unmarshal java.util.Date objects as seen in [this answer by Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3181966/642706).

But what about the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) objects in [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29), such as [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)? Has JAXB been updated to handle this newly built-in data type?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Java SE 8, JAXB has not been updated yet to support the *java.time* types.

Indeed, there is an [issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1174) related to this in the reference implementation.

You need to create and use an [`XmlAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) to handle those types. Use an approach similar to that done with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) as described in this posting, [JAXB and Joda-Time: Dates and Times](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html).

You may be able to use [this implementation of adapters for *java.time*](https://github.com/migesok/jaxb-java-time-adapters).

Comment: That post is about [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Are you saying that JAXB has not been updated for the new built-in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) objects and I need to something similar to handling Joda-Time?

Comment: @BasilBourque - JAXB has not been updated yet to support the `java.time` types.  The impelementation of the adapters will be similar to the linked blog post.

Comment: There is also an implementation for Java 8: https://github.com/migesok/jaxb-java-time-adapters

Answer (score 1):

We couldn't use the library linked in the accepted answer as it glosses over an important detail: In XML Schema date/time values allow the timezone offset to be missing. An adapter must be able to handle this situation. Also, the fact that Java doesn't have a date-only datatype must be supported.

[jTextTime library](https://github.com/Addicticks/jTextTime) solves this.

The library revolves around the JDK8 `OffsetXXX` date/time classes as these are the (only) natural equivalent for the XML Schema types `date`, `dateTime` and `time`.

Use like this:

**Add dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.addicticks.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtexttime</artifactId>
    <version> ... latest ...</version>
</dependency>
```

**Annotate your classes:**

```
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OffsetDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name="dateTime")
    public OffsetDateTime getLastOrderTime() {
        ....
    }

    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OffsetDateXmlAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name="date")
    public OffsetDateTime getDateOfBirth() {   // returns a date-only value
        ....
    }
}
```

If you don't want to annotate each class individually then you can use package-level annotations as explained [here](https://github.com/Addicticks/jTexttime/wiki/JAXB-type-adapter-classes-for-java.time#usage-in-classes).

If you generate Java classes from XSD files using the xjc tool then this is [also explained](https://github.com/Addicticks/jTexttime/wiki/JAXB-type-adapter-classes-for-java.time#usage-with-xjc).