# Unexpected values when unmarshalling Date and Currency attributes using JAXB

Tags: java, date, soap, jaxb, currency

I am trying to umarshall xml response to java pojo. Having issues with date and currency values while unmarshalling using jaxb

Results of unmarshalling, the currency field value not getting mapped(null) and date field is mapped to some numbers(like 1503979200000)

Could someone please let me know where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Below is my code:
unmarshall code:
       JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Item.class);
        Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Item output = 
 (Item)um.unmarshal(soapMessage.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());

Pojo:

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "item" )
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)  

public class Item{

 @XmlElement( name = "bl" )
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
 private Date docDate;

 @XmlElement( name = "sd" )
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
 private Date dueDate;

 @XmlElement( name = "bu" )
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
 private Date postingDate;

 @XmlElement( name = "wr" )
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CurrencyAdapter.class)
 private Currency amount;

...
```

}

Date value in XML is in the format of yyyy-MM-dd

Result after unmarshalling:
amount = null docDate=1503979200000 dueDate=1503979200000 postingDate=1503979200000

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: results of unmarshalling is, the currency value not getting mapped(null) and date is mapped to some numbers(like 1503979200000)

Comment: Did you mean [*marshalling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) (serializing to XML) rather than *unmarshalling* (instantiating a Java object by reading XML input)?

Comment: @basil bourque I am trying to unmarshall XML to Java and while doing date(to miliseconds) and currency(setting to null) attributes are not getting set

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

- Feature, not a bug.
- Your number `1_503_979_200_000L` is a count of milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

Tips:

- Use *java.time* classes instead of legacy date-time classes.
- Use *ISO 8601* formats when serializing date-time values to text.

## Count-from-epoch

Your [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object is being serialized as a count of milliseconds since the [epoch reference moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Sometimes called [Unix Time, or POSIX Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

## java.time

The `java.util.Date` class you are using is one of the terrible old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Do not use these classes! Years ago they were supplanted by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Specifically, `Date` was replaced by `Instant`. Both represent a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), but [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) resolves to the finer level of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

```
long input = 1_503_979_200_000L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( input  );
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-08-29T04:00:00Z

According to [the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24251661/642706) on [my Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24251183/642706), JAXB has not yet been updated for *java.time*. However, adapters are available, such as [this one](https://github.com/jaxb-java-time-adapters/jaxb-java-time-adapters).

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8061](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines practical useful formats for serializing date-time values as text. They are easy to parse by machine. They are easy to read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

## Example app

Here is a simple little example app to demonstrate how to use the *java.time* class `Instant`.

We added the [*JAXB adapters for Java 8 Date and Time API (JSR-310) types*](https://github.com/jaxb-java-time-adapters/jaxb-java-time-adapters) library via Maven. We need this adapter for `Instant` as JAXB has not yet been updated for *java.time* types. Hopefully that update can happen if we see swifter development with the [*Jakarta EE*](https://jakarta.ee) organization.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.migesok</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-java-time-adapters</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

First, our simple little business-object class `Event` with a pair of properties, `when` and `description`.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import com.migesok.jaxb.adapter.javatime.InstantXmlAdapter;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Event {

    private Instant when;
    private String description;

    // ---------------|  Constructors  |-------------------------

    public Event ( Instant when , String description ) {
        this.when = when;
        this.description = description;
    }

    // ---------------|  Accessors  |-------------------------

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter ( InstantXmlAdapter.class )
    public Instant getWhen () {
        return when;
    }

    public void setWhen ( Instant when ) {
        this.when = when;
    }

    public String getDescription () {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription ( String description ) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    // ---------------|  Object  |-------------------------

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "Event{ " +
                "when=" + when +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                " }";
    }
}
```

Instantiate a business object.

```
Event e = new Event( Instant.now() , "Devoxx" );
System.out.println("e.toString(): " + e);
System.out.println(""); // blank line.
```

> e.toString(): Event{ when=2018-07-31T04:03:43.113356Z, description='Devoxx' }

Run our JAXB code.

```
try {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( Event.class );
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT , true );
    JAXBElement< Event > jaxbElement = new JAXBElement< Event >( new QName( "event" ) , Event.class , e );
    marshaller.marshal( jaxbElement , System.out );
} catch ( JAXBException e1 ) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Results:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<event>
    <description>Devoxx</description>
    <when>2018-07-31T04:03:43.113356Z</when>
</event>
```

We see the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format was used in the XML, `2018-07-31T04:03:43.113356Z`. The `Z` on the end means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), and is pronounced `Zulu`.

Much more readable than `1503979200000`!

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).